# What's your favorite keyboard?

Tags: tools, typing

After using a Logitech Internet Pro keyboard for the past several years, as well as an Acer OEM keyboard occasionally, I'm seriously thinking about getting a new keyboard. I write upwards of 7,000 words a week, and I'd like something that just feels really good to type on. I typically prefer low profile keyboards when I've used them, and definitely want something with thinner keys than the Internet Pro. I had considered getting the Apple Wireless keyboard so I could use it with my iPad, but seems odd to get it considering I use a Windows 7 PC most of the time and don't own a Mac.

With that in mind, what is your favorite keyboard and why? I'd really like to know what keyboards other writers love. Hopefully that'll help me make a better decision. I'd rather not spend *too much* on one, but sometimes quality is worth paying for. I just want to make sure I'm getting something I'll use for a long time for the price!

Comment: I'm voting to close, since "what to buy" questions are just not a good fit for SE sites in general.

Comment: @justkt - I'm a college student and tech writer. I essentially HTML formatted articles on WordPress and APA formatted Word documents.

Comment: @JSBangs - I'm hoping to find what others find to be the best features about their keyboards, and what to look for in particular. I thought other writers might have more experience on this. I just jumped in with the keyboard I have, and at times my wrists are regretting it.

Comment: How is this not a poll that should be closed immediately?

Comment: I think this is a "tools" question. I definitely research peripherals like keyboards before buying, and peer reviews are part of that data.

Comment: @Martha - open a discussion on meta if you like so we can discuss.

Comment: Vote to close as a poll the community question.

Comment: @maguay - for this to be on-topic, I think, it has to be less "what is your favorite" and more "I have these criteria.  What meets them?"  Please use the edit link under your question and update the criteria.  Thanks!

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/what-are-good-keyboards-for-programming

Answer (score 2):

I prefer a buckling-spring keyboard like the old IBM Model M or the ones made by [Clicky Keyboards](http://www.clickykeyboards.com/).  I only wish I could find that feature in a more ergonomic layout.

Buckling-spring keys provide better tactile feedback than bubble keyboards, and I find that causes me to type faster and more lightly (rather than mashing the keys), easing strain on my hands and wrists.

Answer (score 1):

My keyboard has to be hard (I want to feel typing) and heavy (not to fly away when I cough). It is enough.

Comment: Heavy is definitely important. That's perhaps the worst problem of most OEM keyboards shipped with PCs; they slide all over the place. Though that said, the worst is when the keys are so wobbly they feel like they'll fall off.

Answer (score 1):

I had terrible tendonitis in both arms for a while, and I had to get a mega-customizable ergo keyboard.

http://www.comfortkeyboard.com/

They are not cheap, but I didn't have to get CTS surgery either. :) You can rotate each of the three pieces to the point where you can almost type vertically. It takes a while to get used to, and most of my coworkers couldn't figure out how to use the thing (which is a bonus if you don't like other people touching your keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

I use a Microsoft ComfortCurve keyboard at work. I was skeptical at first, but was surprised at how comfortable it actually was after I bought it. It has a fairly simple layout, and I find that I can reach all the important keys with ease. What I really like about it, though, is the way it feels when I type. The keyboard does not slide around (as some do) and each key press is smooth. I do not have to strain my fingers to press down on a key either, unlike some of the OEM keyboards that tend to favour the clickety, typewriter-ish feel.

When it comes to choosing the "right" keyboard, I think it's a personal choice. Like choosing a musical instrument or a car. You have to try out different types then choose the one that complements you.

Answer (score 0):

I use a [Happy Hacking Keyboard Lite2](http://www.pfusystems.com/hhkeyboard/hhkeyboard.html). Though it's not cheap, I have many reasons why:

- Small: it's half the size of a piece of 8 1/2 x 11 sheet of paper
- Fewer Keys: they've "hidden" nearly half of the normal amount of keys (many of which are useless 99.9% of the time) behind a Fn + Key combination.
- Solid / Deep Contact: it's almost impossible to strike adjacent keys on accident, as is so common with shallow striking keyboards.
- Cross Platform: I use an Ubuntu machine at work and a Mac at home, and it saves me even the slightest bit of mental stress to use the same keyboard with the same key mapping.
- Durable: It's extremely durable
- USB: x2 ports easily accessible on the back. With a very long cord, this is great for desktop machines.
- Pleasing sound: the loud but beautiful sound of the keys constantly reminds me that I am very serious about the writing I am doing.